# Calculate the composition $V\overset{ιV}{\mapsto}V^{**}\overset{α^T_B}{→}V^∗$ with $B:V\times V\to F$ be a bilinear map.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, function-and-relation-composition, bilinear-form, dual-spaces

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over a field $F$, and $B:V\times V\to F$ be a bilinear map. Let a  linear map $α_B:V→V^∗$ to the dual space of $V$ be given by $v \mapsto [w \mapsto B(v,w)]$.

Calculate the composition $V\overset{ιV}{\mapsto}V^{**}\overset{α^T_B}{→}V^∗$, where $ιV:V\overset{∼}{\mapsto}V^{**}$ is the canonical isomorphism.

Honestly, this kind of problem seems very tough for me so just have fun with it and I hope anybody can help me, at least give me a clue how to start..

Comment: Write down the definitions of all the involved maps as explicitly as you can. Then, computing the resulting composition is just a matter of putting those definitions together. This is mostly an exercise in keeping track of things.

Comment: Thank you very luch @Thorgott, but actully I'm not sure about the concrete definition of the map $\alpha_B$, is it itself a composition isn't it ? And I think I miss the importance of the dual and double dual spaces here..

Comment: You have given the definition of $\alpha_B$ yourself, haven't you? A vector $v\in V$ is mapped to the linear map $\alpha_B(v)\in V^{\ast}$ (remember that this is the vector space of linear functions $V\rightarrow F$) which is defined by $\alpha_B(v)(w)=B(v,w)$ for all $w\in W$. Now try spelling out what the transpose/dual of this map is and what the canonical isomorphism $\iota_V$ is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $v \in V$ the image of $v$ under the canonical isomorphism is the linear form of defined on $V^*$ by

$$\begin{array}{l|rcl}
(V^*)^* \ni \iota(v) : & V^* & \longrightarrow & F \\
    & \phi & \longmapsto & \iota(v)(\phi) = \phi(v)&\end{array}$$

And by definition of the transpose, $\alpha_B$ is the application

$$\begin{array}{l|rcl}
\alpha_B^T : & (V^*)^* & \longrightarrow & V^* \\
    & \psi & \longmapsto & \alpha_B^T(\psi)&\end{array}$$ defined by

$$\alpha_B^T(\psi)(v) = \psi(\alpha_B(v))$$ for all $v \in V$. We have to identify $ \alpha_B^T \circ \iota$ which is an element of $\mathcal L(V, V^*)$, i.e. for $v \in V$, $(\alpha_B^T \circ \iota)(v) $ is a linear form of $V$ which maps an element $w \in V$ to $[(\alpha_B^T \circ \iota)(v)](w) \in F$. More precisely:

$$[(\alpha_B^T \circ \iota)(v)](w) = \iota(v)(r \mapsto B(w,r))=B(w,v).$$

Finally

$$(\alpha_B^T \circ \iota)(v) = [w \mapsto B(w,v)]$$ or using the terminology of the question, $\alpha_B^T \circ \iota$ is given by $v \mapsto [w \mapsto B(w,v)]$.

Comment: Thank you very much @mathcounterexamples.ne !